# Remove all the "Selections" from a recorded Macro

Tags: excel, select, vba

I recorded this then added the LR = LastRow to make it dynamic but I can not figure out how to remove all the selections that go on

Also these both do the samething but is one way of writting the array `better` then the other i.e `faster`, more `stable`...

Thanks

```
 Selection.FormulaArray = "=ISNUMBER(MATCH(RC[-5]&RC[-6],R1C1:R" & LR & "C1 & R1C2:R" & LR & "C2,0))"

 Selection.FormulaArray = "=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1&A1,$A$1:$A$" & LR & " & $B$1:$B$" & LR & ",0))"
```

Recorded Macro

```
Sub Winding()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim LR As Long

 Set ws = Sheets("Unpivot_RegistrationData")
     LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = ws.Range("G1").Resize(LR, 1)

Range("G1").Select
       Selection.FormulaArray = "=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1&A1,$A$1:$A$" & LR & " & $B$1:$B$" & LR & ",0))"
       Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Rng, Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, preference for `A1` or `R1C1` style should be driven by ease of constructing the formula string.  There is no diffrence in performance or stability

To remove the `Selection` try this
Note that I have removed the `AutoFill`, and applied to formula to the whole range in one step.

```
Sub Winding()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LR As Long

    With Worksheets("Unpivot_RegistrationData")
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("G1:G" & LR)
    End With

    Rng.Cells(1, 1).FormulaArray = _
      "=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1&A1,$A$1:$A$" & LR & " & $B$1:$B$" & LR & ",0))"
    Rng.Cells(1, 1).AutoFill Destination:=Rng, Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Chris and thank you, when I run your sub all the cells in column `G` are `False` which should not be the case

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with your formula?  Is each cells an independant array formula, or is the whole range one array formula? (please update this info into your question)